# Exploring Excel VBA without Microsoft Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Is there any platform can be used to explore Excel VBA without Microsoft Excel?

Probably something like online platform or any open source solution such as LibreOffice?

Comment: There's lots of documentation for VBA. If you want to use it though, you need to software.

Comment: It's a challenging question and must OPEN for more & more discussions as well solutions .

Comment: maybe some of the answers in this article will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536607/read-vba-macros-or-vbaproject-bin-of-an-excel-file-without-opening-it-in-ms-ex

Answer (score 1):

VBA is different from other programming languages such as VB and C++.

VBA does not exist independently, ***it must be attached to the office to be used.***

But VBA is not only EXCEL can be used, such as WORD, ACCESS and other office programs can be used.

If you don’t want to use EXCEL to browse VBA code, then you can only choose to browse from other office software

Comment: The gist of what you saying is correct.  However there is an editor in AutoCAD where you can edit VBA code.  Its not part of the MS Office software series.  It is however no longer officially supported, but still exists and will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use VBA in Microsoft Office applications. For LibreOffice applications you can use LibreOffice Basic which is like a VBA for libreOffice. It has a VBA equivalent syntax but the objects are different.

Answer (score -1):

There are few possibility, but the best possible is Visual Basic Script file (.vbs).

Let me clear that VBA is not an independent software like others, ultimately it needs the host.

Possibly you are thinking to execute MACRO others than standard method.

[Check this link](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/how-to-automatically-run-excel-vba-macros-daily)

Comment: Please write your concern that Y this has been down voted !!

Comment: I didn't downvote this answer, but the very possible reason is that Visual Basic Script and Visual Basic for Applications are not same. VBScript is mainly dependent on Windows Script Host (WSH) and can use COM objects, though it can access Excel through Excel.Application object. And VBA has direct integration, it can't be written in separate script files with any kind of extension, and it is only usable in Microsoft Office applications, especially we use it in Excel, Word and Outlook. It has the most of the basic syntax of VBScript, and can use COM, but can't use WSH. So you got a downvote.

Comment: @WasifHasan,,, the question was "explore Excel VBA without Microsoft Excel?",, and let me remind U that Visual Basic Script file (.vbs). is one the authentic possibilities,, once you try the method I've suggested !!